# Is there any alternative to implement functionality similar to group_concat?

Tags: sql

There is the following table in the MySQL database I used before, which records the tourism influence scores of some cities.

| id | country | points | city |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 102 | UAE | 93 | Dubai |
| 128 | France | 99 | Paris |
| 133 | Spain | 90 | Barcelona |
| 149 | Germany | 80 | Munich |
| 222 | Germany | 88 | Berlin |
| 241 | Spain | 94 | Madrid |
| 777 | Germany | 80 | Heidelberg |
| 900 | Germany | 80 | Hamburg |

I need to find the **top three cities** in **each country** based on their total points. If multiple cities have the same total points, order them by city name in ascending order. If there's no second city, output 'No Second City,' and if there's no third city, output 'No Third City.'

The following is my query.

```
with a as (
select country, concat(city,' (',sum(points),')') city , row_number() over(partition by country order by sum(points) desc, city) rn
  from Cities
 group by country, city
)
select country,
       group_concat(case when rn = 1 then city else null end ) top_city,
       coalesce(group_concat(case when rn = 2 then city else null end ),'No second city') second_city,
       coalesce(group_concat(case when rn = 3 then city else null end ),'No third city') third_city
  from a
 where rn <= 3
 group by 1
 order by 1
```

It will get the expected results:

| country | top_city | second_city | third_city |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| France | Paris(99) | No second city | No third city |
| Germany | Berlin(88) | Hamburg(80) | Heidelberg(80) |
| Spain | Madrid(94) | Barcelona(90) | No third city |
| UAE | Dubai(93) | No second city | No third city |

However, instead of using MySQL, I now use PieCloudDB Database, my above query will get an error:`function group_concat(text) does not exist`. So I want to know if there is any other way to achieve my requirement?

Comment: Can you tell me why you are using group_concat function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using conditional aggregation to transform rows into columns, employing `GROUP_CONCAT()`, which can be accomplished better with `MAX()` (available on pieCloudDB) :

```
with a as (
  select country, concat(city,' (',sum(points),')') city , 
         row_number() over(partition by country order by sum(points) desc, city) rn
  from Cities
  group by country, city
)
select country,
       max(case when rn = 1 then city else null end ) top_city,
       coalesce(max(case when rn = 2 then city else null end ),'No second city') second_city,
       coalesce(max(case when rn = 3 then city else null end ),'No third city') third_city
from a
where rn <= 3
group by 1
order by 1;
```

[Demo on postgresql](https://dbfiddle.uk/IEkqiZBQ)

Answer (score 0):

No need to use `group_concat()`, you can achieve your requirements through `grouping + window functions + left join`.

```
WITH T AS (
        SELECT country, CONCAT(city, ' (', points, ')') AS city,
        RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY country ORDER BY points DESC, city) AS rk
        FROM (SELECT country, SUM(points) AS points, city FROM Cities GROUP BY 1, 3) AS t
    )
SELECT t1.country, t1.city AS top_city,
    COALESCE(t2.city, 'No second city') AS second_city,
    COALESCE(t3.city, 'No third city') AS third_city
FROM
    T AS t1
    LEFT JOIN T AS t2 ON t1.country = t2.country AND t1.rk = t2.rk - 1
    LEFT JOIN T AS t3 ON t2.country = t3.country AND t2.rk = t3.rk - 1
WHERE t1.rk = 1
ORDER BY 1
```

This is the regular approach and I believe it will work with PieCloudDB.